# adding a node at the end of a Linked List (java)

Tags: java, linked-list

This is my code for the linked list (not the main). The method "addLast" gives me the following error and i'm not sure how to resolve it: "non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context".
It is talking about this line: return new Node(x,null); 
I'd appreciate any help as to how to resolve this issue. Thank you

```
public class LinkedList
{

  private class Node 
    { 
        int item;
        Node link;

        public Node ()
        {
            item = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            link = null;

        }

        public Node (int x, Node p)

        {  
            item = x;
            link = p;

        }

    } //End of node class


    private Node head;


    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    //adds a node to the start of the list with the specified data
    //added node will be the first node in the list

    public void addToStart(int x)
    {
        head = new Node(x, head);
    }


    //adds a number at end of list 
    public static Node addLast(Node header, int x)
    { 
        // save the reference to the header so we can return it. 
        Node ret = header; 

        // check base case, header is null. 
        if (header == null) { 
            return new Node(x, null); 
        } 

        // loop until we find the end of the list 
        while ((header.link != null)) { 
            header = header.link; 
        } 

        // set the new node to the Object x, next will be null. 
        header.link = new Node(x, null); 
        return ret; 
    }


    //displays the list
    public void printList()
    {
        Node position = head;
        while(position != null)
        {
            System.out.print(position.item + " ");
            position = position.link;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `static` qualifier from `addLast` -- it needs to be non-static to have a list to add to the end of.  It also should not take (or return) a `Node`, as `Node` is a private nested class, so code outside this class doesn't know (or care) what a `Node` is, so can't have one to pass.

```
public void addLast(int x) {
    if (head == null) head = new Node(x, null);
    else {
        Node p = head;
        while (p.link != null) p = p.link;
        p.link = new Node(x, null); } }
```

Comment: I can't because addLast will have to be static in order for my main to access it.

Comment: No, your main just needs a `LinkedList` to call `addLast` on -- `list = new LinkedList(); list.addLast(5); list.addLast(6);`...

Comment: can you please explain the for loop?

Comment: It scans to the end of the list.  Rewritten as a `while` to make it clearer

Comment: so when i type in your code, for the line head = new Node (x); it gives me the following error : no suitable constructor found for Node(int)

Comment: Sorry, the way you have `Node` defined you need to give it an explicit `null` second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions:

Make `Node` a static nested class:

```
private static class Node { ... }
```

Or, make the `addLast` method an instance method:

```
public Node addLast(Node header, int x) { ... }
```

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be a static nested class, though it may make sense for it to be so.  Making it non-static is irrelevant to the OPs problem.

Comment: @ChrisDodd True, it's not absolutely necessary, but it seems more logical for `Node` to be independent of `LinkedList`.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the list.  Making it non-static allows the Node to refer back to the head of the list it is contained in, which may be useful for some algortihms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error line:

> non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Remove the `static` for the method `addLast`.

```
public Node addLast(Node header, int x) 
{
  ....
}
```